# cppcheck, how inline-suppression works with misra add-on

Tags: cppcheck, misra

I tried inline suppression with CppCheck and misra add-on:

My example:

```
    // /* Send number of data */
```

Generate the error:

> "misra-c2012-3.1" severity="style" msg="The character sequences /* and
>   // shall not be used within a comment"

But if I tried

```
    // cppcheck-suppress  misra-c2012-3.1
    // /* Send number of data */
```

I always have the error.
I tried different syntax about the Id:

- misra-c2012-3.1
- misra_c2012_3.1
- misra_3.1
- misra-3.1

Each time, the error is always raised.

I use the option --inline-suppr

Comment: Why exactly do you have comments inside comments to begin with though? Is it some Doxygen thing?

Comment: No, it's just for an example to test the inline suppression, easy way to break a MISRA rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have found a bug.
Your approach looks correct to me.

For the following C code (here in the file misra_suppression_test.c) the suppression works:

```
// cppcheck-suppress misra-c2012-2.7
void misra_2_7_unused_param (int *param1, int unused_param)
{
    *param1 = 42U;
}
```

Without `--inline-suppr` the violation is reported:

```
$ ./cppcheck --enable=style --addon=misra misra_suppression_test.c
Checking misra_suppression_test.c ...
misra_suppression_test.c:2:6: style: misra violation (use --rule-texts=<file> to get proper output) [misra-c2012-2.7]
void misra_2_7_unused_param (int *param1, int unused_param)
     ^
```

With `--inline-suppr` the violation is no longer reported:

```
$ ./cppcheck --enable=style --addon=misra --inline-suppr misra_suprpession_test.c
Checking misra_suppression_test.c ...
```

It looks like suppression is not working for rule 3.1 or so.

Comment: I did the same test as yours. The violation is not reported. So yes, apparently it's a bug. Some rules works and others don't... I will report it. Thanks :)